# What is Difference between Insert Data in Disconnected Scenario vs Insert Data in Connected Scenario, in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

What is difference between Insert Data in Disconnected Scenario vs Insert Data in Connected Scenario , in EF Core?

Sample of Insert Data in Disconnected:

```
     //Disconnected entity
    var std = new Student(){ Name = "Bill" };

    using (var context = new SchoolContext())
    {
        //1. Attach an entity to context with Added EntityState
        context.Add<Student>(std);

        //or the followings are also valid
        // context.Students.Add(std);
        // context.Entry<Student>(std).State = EntityState.Added;
        // context.Attach<Student>(std);

        //2. Calling SaveChanges to insert a new record into Students table
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And sample Insert Data in Connected:

```
using (var context = new SchoolContext())
{
    var std = new Student()
    {
        FirstName = "Bill",
        LastName = "Gates"
    };
    context.Students.Add(std);

    // or
    // context.Add<Student>(std);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This question originated from this site for me => [click here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/saving-data-in-disconnected-scenario-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: You mean *detached*, not *disconnected*. In this case though there's no difference - new entities are detached by definition.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The term "disconnected" is used by site from the link. Also the EF Core documentation - [Disconnected entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities). Other than that, there is no difference for the entity being added. But for related entities through reference navigation properties there *is* a difference.

Comment: @IvanStoev the very same thing was called `Detached entities` in the EF docs. `Connected` vs `Disconnected` referred to whether a cursor was kept open while working with data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, but looks like the "official" term changed in EF Core. And since the question is about EF Core...

Comment: @IvanStoev that doesn't mean the dictionary changed, what other ORMs mean when using those terms or what most people mean by disconnected/detached. Just google for `EF detached entities`. It *does* mean that a *lot* of people will get confused. The answer here is an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the connected scenario, the same instance of DbContext is used in retrieving and saving entities.

In the disconnected scenario, the DbContext is not aware of disconnected entities because entities were added or modified out of the scope of the current DbContext instance. So, you need to attach the disconnected entities to a context with appropriate EntityState in order to perform CUD (Create, Update, Delete) operations to the database.

I think connected scenario is best solution because we don't need to create new object of entity.

Comment: The OP asks whether there's a difference when *adding* a new entity